# How to check for exception values like nan,None and infinity

Tags: python, numpy, numeric

I'm coding a validator for a data pipeline and I want to assert that the numbers in my data are all "good" numbers, so I want to check for NaN, Inf or null. Are some kind of function that can test for that and there is more exception values that I should check ?

I think that a test to check if the number is between a range for example [-10,10] will guarantee good numbers, but i want to know if there is a better method

Comment: Why don't reverse your logic. Don't check for non-numbers, check for numbers. A regex can easily handle it. And a simple `not` would reverse the logic again. `np.isreal` would return a mask that is `True` if the value is a `real` number. Not any other objects such as `str`, `None` etc...

Comment: Is your input strings, numbers, lists, numpy arrays, or Panda Series.  Pandas has the most powerful  checker, `numpy` can test float dtype arrays for `nan` and `inf`. None` is a unique python object that requires a `is None` test.

Answer (score 0):

To check if all the numbers in the data are good numbers:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def good_number_checker(number):
    return all(isinstance(number, (int,float)) and math.isfinite(number) and not math.isnan(number) for number in data)

data = [1,2,3]
print(good_number_checker(data)) #Prints True
data = [1,2,3,float("inf")]
print(good_number_checker(data)) #Prints False
```

To check individually:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def good_number_checker(number):
    return isinstance(number, (int,float)) and math.isfinite(number) and not math.isnan(number)

data = [1,2,3,float("inf")]

for number in data:
    if good_number_checker(number)==False:
        print("Bad number " + str(number) +" exists") #Prints Bad number inf exists
```

Comment: Let me know if this solves your issue or you need further help

Answer (score 0):

If your data are in a numpy array `x`, `np.isfinite(x)` returns a boolean array of the same shape than, filled with `True` where `x` has a finite value.